# Best way to create a Midnight DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to create a midnight DateTime

I've just done this:

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
endTime.Subtract(endTime.TimeOfDay);
```

Haven't test it yet, I'm assuming it works but is there a better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Just use `foo.Date`, or [`DateTime.Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today) for today's date

Comment: It is worth considering that people generally think of midnight as the last second of the day, whereas this gives the 1st second of the day (which is a different midnight).  So if you intend to accomplish the popular meaning of midnight, please see Aruna's answer below (and Paul Suart's comment)

Comment: @jdoer1997 - It depends what your app needs to do at midnight. Apps that depend on date, day-of-week, etc. may want to do house keeping tasks at the first tick into the new day.

Comment: If you are dealing with multiple time zones you may want to be careful with DateTime.Today. In this case DateTime.UtcNow.Date might have more desirable results.

Answer (score 26):

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Now `endTime.TimeOfDay.ToString()` returns `"00:00:00"`

Answer (score 19):

[`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) . [`AddDays(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays) . [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date)

Comment: I think `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)` is nicer than this.

Answer (score 17):

DateTime.Today

Answer (score 15):

You can use `DateTime.Today` with exact seconds of the midnight.

```
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime mid = today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Today: {0} , Mid Night: {1}", today.ToString(), mid.ToString()));

    Console.ReadLine();
```

This should print :

```
Today: 11/24/2016 10:00:00 AM , Mid Night: 11/24/2016 11:59:59 PM
```

Comment: This helped a lot and it is exactly what i wanted

Comment: Midnight is the first one - it's the very first second of the day, not the last.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateMidnight = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: In addition to providing some code, please add some additional details about why your solution works and how it differs from previous solutions.

Answer (score -3):

```
    private bool IsServiceDatabaseProcessReadyToStart()
    {
        bool isGoodParms = true;
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        //24 Hour Clock
        string[] timeSpan = currentTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss").Split(':');
        //Default to Noon
        int hr = 12;
        int mn = 0;
        int sc = 0;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeSpan[0]))
        {
            hr = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            isGoodParms = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeSpan[1]))
        {
            mn = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            isGoodParms = false;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeSpan[2]))
        {
            sc = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            isGoodParms = false;
        }

        if (isGoodParms == true )
        {
            TimeSpan currentTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(hr, mn, sc);
            TimeSpan minTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
            TimeSpan maxTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 04, 59);
            if (currentTimeSpan >= minTimeSpan && currentTimeSpan <= maxTimeSpan)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In addition to providing some code, please provide some additional details about why your solution works and how it differs from previous solutions.