# C# datetime midnight time Format

Tags: c#

I want to run a report where i want to pass parameters as  starttime which is yesterday 12 am(midnight) and enddate as today 12 am (mid night), how to get midnight time in  datetime format in c#

Comment: Here is your answer .Check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246225/best-way-to-create-a-midnight-datetime-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you mean new DateTime(2011,1,1, 0,0,0)?

Comment: This system will run daily so it will take yesterday 12 am to today 12 am

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Current date without any time (at midnight)

```
DateTime.Today
```

Yesterday at midnight

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx)

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to
>   00:00:00.

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Today);
```

Output:

> 5/11/2012 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here.Just you have to search properly.Anyways here is the answer ,just use

DateTime.Today for today's date

Answer (score 1):

how about you pass the following format? `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` so if applied in you code:

it should be `2012-05-12 00:00:00` to `2012-05-13 00:00:00`

don't forget to include the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
From Date: DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
To Date:   DateTime.Today
```