# Scheduling a Job with a fixed termination date in asp.NET using chroniton.NETCore

Tags: asp.net, cron, asp.net-core, scheduling, schedule

I'm working on a WebAPI that schedules Events and appointments.In order to do that, I am using the chroniton.NetCore package. I am able to set the schedule using a cron expression or other functions, but is there any way to set a stop date or termination date for the schedule?

```
      var schedule = new EveryXTimeSchedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        var scheduledJob = singularity.ScheduleParameterizedJob(
            schedule, job, "Hello World", true); //starts immediately
```

I wish to stop this job on the next day at midnight without using Task.Delay(since the api is stateless)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of chroniton.NETCore does not support such behaviour out of the box. You can implement your own logic based on fact, that you have information about time range.

- `ScheduleParameterizedJob()` returns an `IScheduledJob` which can be used to cancel the job if needed. You can create additional `RunOnceSchedule` to close your first job on the next day at midnight using

  `Singularity.Instance.StopScheduledJob(IScheduledJob job);`
- you can inherit from `EveryXTimeSchedule` and override `NextScheduledTime` method to return `Chroniton.Constants.Never` if 'next scheduled time' is >= the next day at midnight;

[Best way to create a Midnight DateTime in C# :](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246225/2833802)

```
DateTime nextDayAtMidnight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
```